# Enum class members appearing as defined types not enum members

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I'm implementing an Enum class but it keeps showing up as normal class variables.  For example:

```
from enum import Enum

class test(Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2
    thr = "three"
```

using this I get:

```
>>> print type(test.one)
<type 'int'>
>>> print repr(test.one)
1
>>> print test.one
1

>>> print type(test.thr)
<type 'str'>
>>> print repr(test.thr)    
'three'
>>> print test.thr
three
```

What could be going wrong?

Info:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ python -c "import enum; print enum.__version__"
0.4.4
```

Comment: What `enum` module are you using? It doesn't ship with the Python 2.7 stdlib.

Comment: I installed it using `pip install --user enum` --- is there a way I can make sure this is the version being used?  (I'm on a remote server so maybe something weird is going on)

Comment: YES @kalhartt thank you, you sweet sweet being.  Put this as an answer so I can upvote and mark it?

Comment: If you're interested in the thinking behind introducing `Enum` to the standard library, [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) is worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enum introduced in python 3.4 is backported under [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34). It seems you had the misfortune of installing this [enum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum) package which is entirely different.